# change google static map api language

Tags: google-maps

I want load a map image with google static map api with different language
but language parameter not working

I sure that google map support farsi language in iran area, because when I use google map in dynamic mode all labels are farsi but when I want use static map, language parameter not working

see this examples :

dynamic map : [dynamic map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgD9r.png)

static map : [static map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOL6A.png)

in static map all labels is in English language

language parameter is set to "fa" but it's not working

thanks

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this issue. When I run your example I can see all basemap labels in Farsi. From which region do you run your requests? Did you try adding also a `region` parameter?

Comment: I found problem.
I'll write problem in next comment on question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found problem

when I create link, I would put each parameter in a line.

like this :

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?
        language=fa
        &size=1000x1000
        &markers=color:red|35.73224409216198,51.41823049997345
        &key=AIzaSyDIJ9XX2ZvRKCJcFRrl-lRanEtFUow4piM&scale=1
```

when I write all parameters in one line, The problem was solved.

correct url :

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?language=fa&size=1000x1000&markers=color:red|35.73224409216198,51.41823049997345&key=AIzaSyDIJ9XX2ZvRKCJcFRrl-lRanEtFUow4piM&scale=1
```